# Why does my function only run once per page load?

Tags: javascript, forms, function

I'm writing a script that does a calculation with text inputs in a form. For some reason, my calculation is performed only once per page load. I have to refresh the page to get the function to run again when I press a "calculate" button.

Here's the HTML for my buttons:

```
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate(high, low, common);" />
<input type="reset" />
<div id="result"></div>
```

Here is the calculate function (the variables are defined elsewhere):

```
var calculate = function (high, low, common) {
   if (high.length < 1 || low.length < 1 || common.length <1) {
       document.getElementById('result').innerHTML="Please enter a number for all fields.";
   } else {
       if ((high - common) > (common - low)) {
           document.getElementById('result').innerHTML="Result 1.";
        } else if ((common - low) > (high - common)) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML="Result 2.";
        } else if ((common - low) === (high - common)) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML="Result 3.";
        }
      }
   };
```

Am I doing something that prevents the function from running more than once per page load?

Comment: Where do `high, low, common` come from?

Comment: the code is working fine, if we change values of these three values. output is changing. can you create a jsfiddle of your code.

Comment: @Abhishek, here's a fiddle of the full page. For some reason my program won't go past the first if/else statement now too. http://jsfiddle.net/vdrwh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with your code is that you just setting high, low, common 1st time the page is loaded.
These values remain same all the time.

You should pass your values in onclick event.

Updated your - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abhishekchand/K4h2L/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>

<h1>Calculator</h1>

<!--Form forvalue inputs-->

<form>
    <label for="highRi">Highest:</label><input type ="text" id="highRi" />
    <label for="lowRi">Lowest:</label><input type="text" id="lowRi" />
    <label for="comm">Common Point:</label><input type ="text" id="comm" />

<!--Clicking the button should run the calculate() function-->

    <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate(document.getElementById('highRi').value, document.getElementById('lowRi').value, document.getElementById('comm').value);" />
    <input type="reset" />

<!--Div will populate with result after calculation is performed-->

    <div id="result"></div> 
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">


var calculate = function (high, low, common) {
   if (high.length < 1 || low.length < 1 || common.length <1) {
       document.getElementById('result').innerHTML="Please enter a number for all fields.";
   } else {
       if ((high - common) > (common - low)) {
           document.getElementById('result').innerHTML="Result 1.";
        } else if ((common - low) > (high - common)) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML="Result 2.";
        } else if ((common - low) === (high - common)) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML="Result 3.";
    }
}

}; 

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Or you can simply get those element values in you function call.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Calculator</title>
<meta charset = "UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>

<h1>Calculator</h1>

<!--Form forvalue inputs-->

<form>
    <label for="highRi">Highest:</label><input type ="text" id="highRi" />
    <label for="lowRi">Lowest:</label><input type="text" id="lowRi" />
    <label for="comm">Common Point:</label><input type ="text" id="comm" />

<!--Clicking the button should run the calculate() function-->

    <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate();" />
    <input type="reset" />

<!--Div will populate with result after calculation is performed-->

    <div id="result"></div> 
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">


var calculate = function () {
    var high = document.getElementById('highRi').value;
    var low = document.getElementById('lowRi').value
    var common = document.getElementById('comm').value
   if (high.length < 1 || low.length < 1 || common.length <1) {
       document.getElementById('result').innerHTML="Please enter a number for all fields.";
   } else {
       if ((high - common) > (common - low)) {
           document.getElementById('result').innerHTML="Result 1.";
        } else if ((common - low) > (high - common)) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML="Result 2.";
        } else if ((common - low) === (high - common)) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML="Result 3.";
    }
}

}; 

</script>
```

​
Jsfiddle [See it working](http://jsfiddle.net/abhishekchand/kwWWA/)
​
May be this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

for me also, your code worked if i change the values high, low and common, try this method, it may work for you

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="Calculate" />

var button = document.getElementById("button");
var high = document.getElementById("high").value;
var low = document.getElementById("low").value;
var common = document.getElementById("common").value;
button.addEventListener(onclick, calculate(high, low, common));
```